# Number equations like subsections

Tags: equations, numbering, counters

I would like for equations to share the same counter as subsections. For example if my document is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{A}
\begin{equation} 1+1=2 \end{equation}
\subsection{X}
\begin{equation} 1+1=2 \end{equation}
\begin{equation} 1+1=2 \end{equation}
\subsection{Y}
\begin{equation} 1+1=2 \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I would like this output (produced here through a sneaky use of `\tag`):
[image]

Something similar to how theorems of `amsthm` can be "siblings" with another counter. I am aware of the `\numberwithin` command of amsmath, but this is not what I want. I am also aware of the `aliascnt` package, but since "equation" is an existing counter, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I hope, this is what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\makeatletter
\let\c@equation=\c@subsection
\let\theequation=\thesubsection
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{A}
\begin{equation}
    1+1=2
\end{equation}
\subsection{X}
\begin{equation}
    1+1=2
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    1+1=2
\end{equation}
\subsection{Y}
\begin{equation}
    1+1=2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: No, this is not what I want, sorry. I'm going to include a picture of the output I'd like in my question.

Comment: @nik See my updated answer.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you. (Do you have a reference on how this works? I guess \stepcounter and the like work internally on \c@counter?)

Comment: @nik Your explanation is already pretty accurate. `\c@counter` is the TeX count register the value of the counter is stored in, `\thecounter` just outputs the value of that count register.