# Reset equation numbering after each section

Tags: equations, numbering, counters

I would like to reset equation numbering after each section or subsection. Right now I use

```
\setcounter{equation}{0}
```

I saw in another page you could also reset it by adding the following line to the preamble.

```
\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}
\renewcommand\theequation{\arabic{equation}}
```

But this doesn't seem to work. The equation counters just increment across subsections. It's the same across sections if we changed the preamble to

```
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
```

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't very informative, do you get an error? Have you got `\subsections` (the above won't reset at a `\section`)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.     A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: I don't get an error. It just increments the counter even when moving across a new subsection.

Comment: This question is *not* a duplicate of [Number equations like subsections](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/164048/5001). The earlier posting was concerned with setting up equation numbers so that they contain the section number automaticallz. This new question is about something different: How to execute the  (equivalent of the) instruction `\setcounter{equation}{0}` every time a `\section` or `\subsection` directive is encountered.

Comment: If I understand your posting correctly, you may achieve your objective -- not having to manually execute `\setcounter{equation}{0}` at the start of each section and subsection -- by adding the following four instructions to the preamble: `\makeatletter \@addtoreset{equation}{section} \@addtoreset{equation}{subsection} \makeatother`. Note that this operation is quite different from what's achieved by executing `\numberwithin{equation}{section}` or `\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}`.

Answer (score 41):

Tell LaTeX to reset the equation number whenever `section` or `subsection` is stepped:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chngcntr}

\counterwithin*{equation}{section}
\counterwithin*{equation}{subsection}

\begin{document}
\section{One}
\begin{equation} 2+2=3.99      \end{equation}
\begin{equation} \pi^2=9.86    \end{equation}

\section{Two}
\begin{equation} E=mc^2        \end{equation}
\begin{equation} v=\frac{e}{t} \end{equation}

\subsection{Two \& One}
\begin{equation} 2+2=22 \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: Same as Fran's image]

The instruction `\counterwithin*` is (almost) an interface to `\@addtoreset` (which is better not used if a higher level command provided by a package is available). With `\counterwithin` (without `*`) the counter's representation would be changed, which isn't with the `*`-form.

Comment: Is something like this also possible within `\align` environments?

Comment: @Taunch It should work out of the box

Comment: @egreg How would you reset the counter for `\subsubsection*`?

Comment: @YagnaPatel Not something that can go in a comment. Please, ask a new question with all details.

Comment: this don't work in the "report" environment how to do ? @egreg

Comment: @Vrouvrou Really? It does in my experiment.

Comment: the numbering is like (1.1) @egreg

Comment: @Vrouvrou As expected. What did you expect?

Comment: @egreg (1) iNsteed of (1.1)

Comment: do you have any idea @egreg ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou After the two `\counterwithin*` commands, add `\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}}`